# Camada de saída redes neurais?

Tags: python, machine-learning, redes-neurais

Galera, na construção de uma rede neural para classificação de imagens na minha camada de saída a quantidade de neurônios deve corresponder a quantidade de classes do meu conjunto de dados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim. Por exemplo, se você quer classificar uma imagem como gato, cachorro ou pato, então na sua camada de saída deve ter 3 neurônios (1 para cada classe).